# Unable to pass in Dropdown value to XSLT Param

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to pass a choice from a dropdown into my XSLT in order to filter results. It doesn't want to work properly though for whatever reason.

When I hard-code the appropriate value into the query it gives the desired result. Googling this issue every which way has also not yielded much help. I believe the problem may be in the way xsltProcessor.setParameter is parsing the data, not sending it through correctly to the XSLT.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_schools_in_London,_Ontario [March 12, 2020] -->
<London-Schools>
  <Adult-Education>
    <School short-name="G.A. Wheable" french-immersion="no" before-after-programs="no">
      <Board>Thames Valley District School Board</Board>
      <Address>70 Jacqueline St</Address>
      <Name>G.A. Wheable Adult Education Centre</Name>
      <Coordinates x="482066.845" y="4757710.908" />
      <Website>https://www.tvdsb.ca/en/parents/adult-and-continuing-education.aspx</Website>
    </School>
    <School short-name="Centre for Lifelong Learning" french-immersion="no" before-after-programs="no">
      <Board>London District Catholic School Board</Board>
      <Address>1230 King St</Address>
      <Name>Centre for Lifelong Learning St. Patrick Campus</Name>
      <Coordinates x="483095.5923" y="4760265.75" />
      <Website>http://cfll.ldcsb.ca/</Website>
     </School>
 </Adult-Education>
 <Pre-School>
   <School short-name="Gibbons Park Montessori" french-immersion="no" before-after-programs="no">
     <Board>Private</Board>
     <Address>29 Victoria St</Address>
     <Name>Gibbons Park Montessori Private School</Name>
     <Coordinates x="478120.7488" y="4760883.317" />
     <Website>http://gibbonsparkmontessori.com/</Website>
   </School>
 </Pre-School>
```

XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:param name="schoolTypes" select="//*"/>    
    <xsl:param name="schoolName" select="//*"/>

<xsl:template match="London-Schools">
<html> 
<body>
  <h2>My Schools</h2>

  Number of matches: <xsl:value-of select="count($schoolTypes/School[Name=contains(text(),$schoolName)])"/>
    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th style="text-align:left">School</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Board</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Address</th>
        </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$schoolTypes/School">
                    <xsl:sort select="@short-name"/>
                    <tr>
                        <!--<td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>-->
                        <td>
                            <a href="{Website}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Board"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Address"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Javascript:

```
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 24pt;
        }

        h2 {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 18pt;
        }

        input, button {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 14pt;
        }
    </style>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Schools in Area</title>

</head>

<body>


    <select id="schoolSelect">
        <option value="//*">ALL</option>
        <option value="//Adult-Education">Adult-Education</option>
        <option value="//Pre-School">Pre-School</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="schoolInput" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="RenderXSLT()" />
    <div id="xsltOutputContainer"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function loadXMLDoc(filename)
      {
        if (window.ActiveXObject)
        {
          xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        else
        {
          xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);

        try
        {
          xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"
        }
        catch (err) {}
        xhttp.send("");
        return xhttp.responseXML;
      }

      function RenderXSLT()
      {
        xml = loadXMLDoc("schools.xml");
        xslt = loadXMLDoc("Schools.xslt");

        var characterName = document.getElementById("schoolInput").value;
        characterName = characterName.toUpperCase();
        var schoolType = document.getElementById("schoolSelect").value;
        schoolType = schoolType.toUpperCase();

        if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
        {
          var template = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XslTemplate.6.0");
          template.stylesheet = xslt;

          var proc = template.createProcessor();
          proc.input = xml;
          proc.addParameter("schoolName", characterName);
          proc.addParameter("schoolChoice", schoolType);    

          proc.transform();
          document.getElementById("xsltOutputContainer").innerHTML = proc.output;
        }
        else if (typeof XSLTProcessor !== 'undefined')
        {
          var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
          xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslt);

          xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "schoolName", characterName);
          xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "schoolTypes", schoolSelect);

          var resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
          document.getElementById("xsltOutputContainer").innerHTML = "";
          document.getElementById("xsltOutputContainer").appendChild(resultDocument);
        }
      }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm completely stumped as to why this won't work when trying to pass through the Javascript. Any insights would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to manipulate the XSLT document as an XML DOM document or itself with XSLT to change a `select` or other XPath expression the way you want to do it currently.

If you pass parameters to XSLT then they are of type string or number or boolean and are used in XPath where you use a string or number or boolean so you could use e.g.

```
 <select id="schoolSelect">
    <option value="">ALL</option>
    <option value="Adult-Education">Adult-Education</option>
    <option value="Pre-School">Pre-School</option>
  </select>


 <xsl:param name="schoolTypes" select="''"/>
```

and

```
 <xsl:variable name="schools" select="*[local-name() = $schoolTypes or $schoolTypes = '']/School[contains(Name,$schoolName)]"/>
```

and then `Number of matches: <xsl:value-of select="count($schools)"/>` and the `for-each` with `select="$schools"`.

Comment: I was able to get this mostly working with a few modifications. Thanks! Although the case of submitting 'All' from the form doesn't seem to work. But otherwise it's working fine